# javac - Use --patch-module along with unnamed module classes

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

I've the following directory structure:

```
src
  +- java.base
     +- java
        +- lang
            +- Object.java

  +- java.logging
     +- java
        +- util
            +- logging
                +- FileHandler.java

  +- com
     +- example
        +- MyClass.java
```

`Object`, `FileHandler`, and `MyClass` may cross-reference each other.

So to compile these, I tried running (in `src` directory):

```
javac  --patch-module java.base=java.base \
  --patch-module java.logging=java.logging $(find . -name *.java)
```

But it results in error:

```
error: too many patched modules (java.base,java.logging), use --module-source-path
```

Then I tried:

```
javac  --patch-module java.base=java.base \
  --patch-module java.logging=java.logging \
    --module-source-path . \
      $(find . -name *.java)
```

Then I get the error:

```
error: not in a module on the module source path package com.example;
```

So how can I get these to compile?

---

FYI:

- Assume that javac is run in the `src` directory.
- Classes in `java.base` and `java.logging` may reference classes from `com.example`
- I know how to break encapsulation by use of `--add-reads` flag. What I want is to able to compile without the above two errors.

Comment: I believe `--patch-module` needs to point to compiled classes, not source trees.

Comment: @AlanBateman I think you meant `,` instead of `=`. But these patched classes also reference classes from com.example.

Comment: I think you'll need two javac commands, one to compile the patches, the other to compile the code in com.example. For the first then your command looks right but you might need --add-reads java.base=java.logging if you have references to FileHandle in your Object class.